# How do you convert a list of coefficients to a polynomial in NumPy?

Tags: numpy

Let's say I have a list of coefficients `[1,2,3]`. How do I convert this to `x^3 + 2x^2 + 3` or something similar in NumPy? Is it even possible?

Comment: What exactly do you consider a "polynomial in NumPy"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Something that has the form `ax^n +bx^n-1 +cx^n-2 +...`

Comment: That's a mathematical idea, how do you want to represent it in Python code or in NumPy? What do you want to do with it once you have it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 In NumPy it should look similar to that. In a previous program of mine I managed to achieve this but in this program I am left with a list of coefficients. Once I have it I want to substitute a value for x (I already know how to do this).

Comment: Why don't you do it like you did it in your previous program?

Comment: So you want a function?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I guess, yes.

Comment: If you've tried something, show the code and its problem(s).  Otherwise you'll get downvotes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [in the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.html#transition-guide), which I recommend reading:

```py
>>> p1 = np.polynomial.Polynomial([3, 2, 1])
>>> p1
Polynomial([3., 2., 1.], domain=[-1,  1], window=[-1,  1])
>>> p1(0)
3.0
```

Note that the order of coefficients is reversed.

Comment: Does this code return a polynomial as described in the question?

Comment: Gonna go with "yes" on that one. Try a couple of values and compare with what you'd expect.

Comment: I'm going to try a few values and I will get back to you.

Comment: @MathGeek - This solution returns the correct polynomial, as opposed to the conversion in the question (you missed the coefficient for *0*x*)

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Do we really need that?

Comment: Yes, how would you expect the underlying code to know whether you're ignoring, say, x or x^2? Also, thanks @MichaelSzczesny, missed that one due to the test value I picked.